# How to pass argument to pytest test in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, ide, pytest

I'm using Eclipse IDE for a project which uses pytest to write test cases. I have configured the pyunit environment to use "py.test runner" instead of "PyDev test runner", however, I'm not able to pass any arguments for pytest.

So this is the sample command I run in terminal -

```
pytest --server-version=5.0.0-3516 --sync-gateway-version=1.5.0-557 --sync-gateway-config-file resources/sync_gateway_configs/sync_gateway_default_cc.json --mode=cc testsuites/syncgateway/functional/tests/
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: You should remove the pycharm tag since your question deals with eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figure out the way to pass the argument and select the test case one wants to run. So here is the snapshot of how to pass the argument.

[image]

To run a specific case use ctl + f9 and then select the case of that file. Now to debug it select the case using shift key.

Hope this helps others